# What does 'data coverage' mean when talking about ETL processes?

Tags: distributed-system, apache-kafka, etl

I was watching [this talk about ETL's shortcomings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I32hmY4diFY) and the solutions provided by the Kafka platform but I don't quite understand what the speaker is referring to when she says

> ETL tools have been around for a decade, yet data coverage in warehouses is still low.

What does 'data coverage' mean in this scenario? Is she trying to say that not all data from databases is eventually transferred to data warehouses?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is how I interpret that.  Data stored in data warehouses is imported from primary sources.  The effort required to bring in data is non-trivial so therefore much of the source data is not available in the data warehouse.  Typically this means that you might have every address of every customer but you don't have any birth dates, for example.  It's not that you are missing pieces of data within the scope of what is modeled.  That more or less negates the value of the warehouse.